# How/What is good way to customize elements from the bootstrap design?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am practicing to make websites and I am using **Bootstrap** themes for the design of the websites, but I want to change the design of some things.

For example I want to change some colors in the buttons, make navigation transparent, and move some containers.

Should I add properties in my Bootstrap `CSS` file, or should I make new `CSS` file and select the elements I want to modify from the Bootstrap theme there?

If making new `CSS` file is the better way should I add 1 more class or `ID` for the selection or just select the elements from the Bootstrap class names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best practice should be to use **[Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)** and customize the Bootstrap theme.

If something is not available on the theme, then, you should add an additional `CSS` file (from less/sass/plain css) and override the classes you want.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap provides you with the LESS files you need to compile the css.

Make all your changes there and recompile the css to suit your needs. This is the easiest way to customise the standard color schemes, mobile breakpoints etc.

If you have never used CSS pre-processors before it is worth looking into for this alone.

Comment: so for example if i want my navigation inside my header to be with 0 margin i have to download the less file and change it from there and save the changes ?

Comment: It really depends on the level of changes you are making. You can overwrite the stock settings by added a class of your own and adding the correct styles to it.

If you are using the LESS files you would have to re-compile it all and link the new raw css file. Not ideal if you are only making small changes.

To adjust the margin you can either apply style in the head section, do it inline, or stick an '!important' tag next to the item in the stylesheet. All of these should (depending on your setup) overwrite the default css.

Answer (score 0):

Good option will be to add an additional .class tag to your required element and change its property locally. Main reason for this is you should not  change the core of the Bootstrap design.

Create a class called class="my_Button" and add it to your button element tag like

```
<button type="button" class="btn my_Button" >Button</button>
```

and change its property like this is same file or create a separate CSS file

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .my_button { 
            bottom:100% !important; top:auto !important;
         width:170px;
        }

   </style>
```

other option will be to change inline

```
<button type="button" class="btn my_Button" style="width: 170px">Button</button>
```